# can we see an swf file corresponding to an fla online?

Tags: flash, fla

Actually I donot have flash in my computer.So I want to see the swf of an fla file that is in my desktop. can we do this online?

Comment: No, not as far as I know I'm afraid. I imagine it might be possible to [reverse engineer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494617/is-there-an-unofficial-flash-fla-spec) the fla format and develop a tool to compile the fla. There is no other tool that I know of. It might be easier to use the trial version or ask a friend that has Flash installed to compile the fla and send you the swf file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think George's solution [(download a free trial of Flash CS5)](http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/tdrc/index.cfm?product=flash) is the best. Otherwise you could try this one or the trial version:

http://www.xlinksoft.com/convert-to-swf/fla-to-swf.html

Good luck.